# do they make a manual propress tool for large pipes?

Tags: plumbing, steam

Looking at moving some steam pipes. Happened upon pro press tools that are.. very pricey but I like the tech. Was wondering if they make a huge manual crimper for large pipes like they have for PEX as I don't want to buy the power tool. Anything out there?

Comment: Ask at your local tool rental about renting the power tool. They have it, or they don't, but without asking you don't know.

Comment: Yeah, unless you're going to be doing a _lot_ of piping, rental is most likely going to be _way_ cheaper than buying.

Comment: local rentals don't have it. that's why I started wondering about a hand tool.

Comment: Steam and crimps don’t compute. Most steam is welded. I have seen low pressure steam that is threaded, but never crimped.

Comment: @EdBeal https://info.viega.us/blog/how-to-use-megapress-fittings-for-steam

Comment: You mean like this? https://www.amazon.com/IBOSAD-Fittings-Hydraulic-Crimping-Fitting%EF%BC%8CHydraulic/dp/B094V67QPP

Comment: @MonkeyZeus yeah, but for 2" or 1.5" Steam fittings.
I want to save some time and effort on my project without dropping 6k for a propress and claw set ..if possible.

Comment: Sounds like this could be one of those situations where calling a professional will be cheaper than doing it yourself. If a professional costs more than $6k then buying the right tool will be worth it. You can sell it second-hand rather quickly I would imagine.